# Read a cookie value set from a web api in an MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing a problem with a Web Api and have a question:

In MVC controller, I can't read a cookie value set from an Asp.Net Web Api.

Web Api

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage AddToCart(Interface.Models.CartModel CartModel)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage Response = null;
        try
        {

            // Do some thing

            Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var ShoppingCartDetailsCookie = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue("CartDetails", "value");
            ShoppingCartDetailsCookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
            ShoppingCartDetailsCookie.Path = "/";
            ShoppingCartDetailsCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
            Response.Headers.AddCookies(new System.Net.Http.Headers.CookieHeaderValue[] { ShoppingCartDetailsCookie });


            Response.Content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<Invoices>(Cart, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            return Response;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.RaiseError(ClassName, "AddToCart", ex);
            goto ThrowInternalServerError;
        }

    ThrowInternalServerError:
        Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        Response.Headers.Add("Message", Content.Shared.UnExpectedError);
        return Response;
    }
```

Controller
public class SharedController : Controller
    {

```
    public ActionResult ShoppingCart()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["CartDetails"] != null)
            {
                var StrShoppingCartDetails = Request.Cookies["CartDetails"].Value;
                //Do some thing
            }


        return PartialView("ShoppingCart", ShoppingCart);
    }

}
```

I traced the cookie from chrome developer tool and found that the domain was set to ".domainname" rather than "domainname". Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you solve this ? I know it's old thread, but i'm facing same issue.